# state wont display data on reload Ui-Router and angularfire

Tags: angular-ui-router, angularfire

I have an SPA 'blog' using ui-router and using firebase as a backend with Angular Fire. The blog page calls the array no problem and loads correctly. When i select an individual post it loads with the $stateParams({id:post.$id}) from the array pulled from firebase via Posts.

however when i refresh that page, the unique post is lost.

code as follows: Router =

```
            .state(homeState = {
            name: 'root.home.post',
            url: '/{{postId}}',
            views: {
                'main@': {
                    templateUrl: 'views/post/post.html'
                }
            }
        })
```

post.js =

```
        var id = $stateParams.postId; // console.logs correctly even after refresh
        var ref = Posts; //console.logts $resolved: false after refresh though data from main page still in the array
        var post = ref.$getRecord(id); //console.logs as null after refresh
        $scope.post = post;
```

Not sure if thats enough to go on, but i have struggled with this for a few hours now and want to sleep. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

fixed my own problem (was two fold)

Updated post.js to include the update of the $scope after .$loaded as it was loading after the rest of the page was painted:

```
            var id = $stateParams.postId;
        console.log(id);
        var ref = Posts.$loaded().then(function(ref){
          var post = ref.$getRecord(id);
            $scope.post = post;
        });
```

I also updated the routes to remove {} around the parameter:

```
            .state(postState = {
            name: 'root.post',
            url: '/post/{postId}',
            views: {
                'main@': {
                    templateUrl: 'views/post/post.html'
                }
            },

        })
```